# R: Integrate: Max number of subdivisions reached, roundoff error

Tags: r, function

I came across an interesting but rather annoying problem.

I am trying to integrate a function which has been calculated from a dataset.
The data can be found here: [Link to sample.txt](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15487093/sample.txt).

I start by fitting a line to my data. this can be done linear with `approxfun` or non-linear with `splinefun`. In my example below I use the latter. 
Now, when I try to integrate the fitted function I run into the error

- `maximum number of subdivisions reached`

but when I increase the subdivision I get

- `roundoff error`

From the values in my sample code, you can see that for this specific dataset the threshold is 754->755.

My colleague has no problem to integrate this dataset in Matlab. Is there a way to manipulate my data to integrate? Is there another method for numerical integration in R?

[image]

```
data<-read.table('sample.txt',sep=',')
colnames(data)<-c('wave','trans')
plot(data$wave,data$trans,type='l')

trans<- -1 * log(data$trans)
plot(data$wave,trans,type='l')

fx.spline<-splinefun(data$wave,trans)

#Try either
Fx.spline<-integrate(fx.spline,min(data$wave),max(data$wave))
#Above: Number of subdivision reached
Fx.spline<-integrate(fx.spline,min(data$wave),max(data$wave),subdivisions=754)
#Above: Number of subdivision reached
Fx.spline<-integrate(fx.spline,min(data$wave),max(data$wave),subdivisions=755)
#Above: Roundoff error
```

Comment: Consider posting the fitted function.  I do not seem to be getting parameter estimates, although maybe that is not how splinefun works, or I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Your data looks spectacularly "flat," so maybe calling `integrate` and setting the conversion limit to something like 1e-9 via the `rel.tol` and `abs.tol` arguments will get you an answer that's plenty accurate.

Comment: @MarkMiller There is a good tutorial here: http://casoilresource.lawr.ucdavis.edu/drupal/node/896. To plot the function you can write `plot(data$wave,fx.spline(data$wave),type='l')`

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I changed the tolerances to the lowest possible value but it does not change anything. The question is, why is Matlab doing it and R not :). I am aware that this curve is flat. It is a spectra of hydrogen chloride. Sadly I can't change chemistry

Comment: I got this to work: Fx.spline <- integrate(fx.spline, 2550, 3100,  subdivisions = 754) but so far not for the full range of x values.

Comment: I did play around with the limits as well and managed to get a value for narrow ones. Probably those sub-0 values over 2900 cause the integration to fail. If I do `trans+1` it actually works with the full range. But obviously the resulting value is useless. If i do `trans+0.1` the resulting integral is negative (?)

Comment: This seemed to work.  It covers most of the range:  Fx.spline <- integrate(fx.spline, 2500, 3160, subdivisions = 1200).  But using 2490 instead of 2500 does not work.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping. I accepted Hans' answer as it is working without much fiddeling and I need to process a large quantity of data via lapply

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many integration routines in R, and you can find some of them by 'RSiteSearch'ing or by using the 'sos' package.

For example, package `pracma` has several implementations, for instance

```
quad(fx.spline,min(data$wave),max(data$wave))   # adaptive Simpson
# [1] 2.170449                                  # 2.5 sec
quadgk(fx.spline,min(data$wave),max(data$wave)) # adaptive Gauss-Kronrod
# [1] 2.170449                                  # 0.9 sec
quadl(fx.spline,min(data$wave),max(data$wave))  # adaptive Lobatto
# [1] 2.170449                                  # 0.8 sec
```

Please not that these are pure R scripts and therefore slower than, e.g., the compiled `integrate` routine with such an oscillating function.

Comment: Good answer and a match to Matlab results. I am still learning R, but finding things in the documentations or searching for the correct terms is sometimes not that straight forward